# How to create a status icon in either Notification Area or Indicator Applet?

Tags: python, linux, gtk, glade

I was wondering that I could not find a tutorial on how to do this. Many of the application on my system has notification area icons and a simple popup menu is attached with most of them. Can anyone tell me how to do this? If some one can do an example that works with **Linux + GTK + Glade + Python**, that will be really great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this StatusIcon tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20130224082059/http://learngtk.org/pygtk-tutorial/statusicon.html).